# How to sort a complex list on two different keys

Tags: python, sorting

I have a weird list built in the following way:

```
[[name_d, 5], [name_e, 10], [name_a, 5]]
```

I want to sort it first by the number (desc) and then, if the number is the same, by the name (asc). So the result I would like to have is:

```
[[name_e, 10], [name_a, 5], [name_d, 5]]
```

I tried to think to a lambda function that I can use in the sort method, but I'm not sure I can do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort Python list with two keys but only one in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693373/sort-python-list-with-two-keys-but-only-one-in-reverse-order)

Comment: I do not understand why mine has been marked as duplicate when the other question is 5 years younger...

Comment: The age has nothing to do with it.  They dont want duplicates

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sort functions in python allow to pass a function as sort key:

```
l = [[name_d, 5], [name_e, 10], [name_a, 5]]
# copy
l_sorted = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1] * -1, x[0]))
# in place
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1] * -1, x[0]))
```

***Edits:***
1. Sort order
2. Demonstrate copy and in place sorting

Comment: he needs descending sorting for the number

Comment: this doesn't work in the way I want, because it sorts also the name in desc (or asc) mode

Comment: @Giovanni: it's not a black box. Do you see how it is solved? and you cannot modify it to suit your problem?

Comment: Corrected the sort order. Like SilentGhost said already - it should have been obvious how to change the order.

Comment: btw: if you don't want to copy the listL `l.sort(key=lambda...)`

Comment: @SilentGhost, Sorry, I didn't know that I could invert the sorting with the "-"

Comment: It solves my problem. But I don't understand what x[1] * -1 means. An explanation would  be better.

Answer (score 2):

You may sort the list twice to get the result, just reverse the order:

```
import operator

l = [[name_d, 5], [name_e, 10], [name_a, 5]]

l.sort(operator.itemgetter(1))
l.sort(operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

Then you will get the sorted list as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give your list a name - "arr"

```
arr.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0],-x[1]),reverse=True)
```

output - [[name_e,10],[name_d,5],[name_a,5]]

Answer (score -1):

Here's something I whipped up (to solve the same type of problem). I've only checked it with my latest versions of installed Python (OS X). The import parts below are the (clunkily-named) sort keys: **sortKeyWithTwoListOrders** and **sortKeyWith2ndThen1stListValue**

---

```
#Tested under Python 2.7.1 & Python 3.2.3:

import random # Just to shuffle for demo purposes

# Our two lists to sort
firstCol=['abc','ghi','jkl','mno','bcd','hjk']
secondCol=[5,4,2,1]

# Build 2 dimensional list [[firstCol,secondCol]...]
myList = []
for firstInd in range(0, len(firstCol)):
  for secondInd in range(0, len(secondCol)):
    myList = myList + [[firstCol[firstInd],secondCol[secondInd]]]

random.shuffle(myList)

print ("myList (shuffled):")
for i in range(0,len(myList)):
  print (myList[i])

def sortKeyWithTwoListOrders(item):
  return secondCol.index(item[1]), firstCol.index(item[0])

myList.sort(key=sortKeyWithTwoListOrders)
print ("myList (sorted according to strict list order, second column then first column):")
for i in range(0,len(myList)):
  print (myList[i])

random.shuffle(myList)

print ("myList (shuffled again):")
for i in range(0,len(myList)):
  print (myList[i])

def sortKeyWith2ndThen1stListValue(item):
  return item[1], item[0]

myList.sort(key=sortKeyWith2ndThen1stListValue)
print ("myList (sorted according to *values*, second column then first column):")
for i in range(0,len(myList)):
  print (myList[i])
```

---

```
myList (shuffled):
['ghi', 5]
['abc', 2]
['abc', 1]
['abc', 4]
['hjk', 5]
['bcd', 4]
['jkl', 5]
['jkl', 2]
['bcd', 1]
['ghi', 1]
['mno', 5]
['ghi', 2]
['hjk', 2]
['jkl', 4]
['mno', 4]
['bcd', 2]
['bcd', 5]
['ghi', 4]
['hjk', 4]
['mno', 2]
['abc', 5]
['mno', 1]
['hjk', 1]
['jkl', 1]
myList (sorted according to strict list order, second column then first column):
['abc', 5]
['ghi', 5]
['jkl', 5]
['mno', 5]
['bcd', 5]
['hjk', 5]
['abc', 4]
['ghi', 4]
['jkl', 4]
['mno', 4]
['bcd', 4]
['hjk', 4]
['abc', 2]
['ghi', 2]
['jkl', 2]
['mno', 2]
['bcd', 2]
['hjk', 2]
['abc', 1]
['ghi', 1]
['jkl', 1]
['mno', 1]
['bcd', 1]
['hjk', 1]
myList (shuffled again):
['hjk', 4]
['ghi', 1]
['abc', 5]
['bcd', 5]
['ghi', 4]
['mno', 1]
['jkl', 1]
['abc', 1]
['hjk', 1]
['jkl', 2]
['hjk', 5]
['mno', 2]
['jkl', 4]
['ghi', 5]
['bcd', 1]
['bcd', 2]
['jkl', 5]
['abc', 2]
['hjk', 2]
['abc', 4]
['mno', 4]
['mno', 5]
['bcd', 4]
['ghi', 2]
myList (sorted according to *values*, second column then first column):
['abc', 1]
['bcd', 1]
['ghi', 1]
['hjk', 1]
['jkl', 1]
['mno', 1]
['abc', 2]
['bcd', 2]
['ghi', 2]
['hjk', 2]
['jkl', 2]
['mno', 2]
['abc', 4]
['bcd', 4]
['ghi', 4]
['hjk', 4]
['jkl', 4]
['mno', 4]
['abc', 5]
['bcd', 5]
['ghi', 5]
['hjk', 5]
['jkl', 5]
['mno', 5]
```

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't need to be a lambda function you pass into the `sort` method, you can actually provide a real function since they are first-class objects in python.

```
L.sort(my_comparison_function)
```

Should work just fine

Comment: -1  Comparison function goes away in Python 3, whereas the other answer is future proof.

Comment: I thought about this, but how can I write a comparison function that works on two different keys? basically I need a f((x[0],x[1]), (y[0],y[1]))

Comment: @Steven: what are you talking about? this answer might be useless, but not for the reasons you state. [Read the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

Comment: @SilentGhost  Maybe I'm misreading, but when I look at the linked docs i see that sort accepts a /key/ function in python 3, but not a /comparison/ function.

Comment: @Steven: and what is key function if not a comparison function?

Comment: @SilentGhost  A comparison function is called on pairs of items and "should return a negative integer if self < other, zero if self == other, a positive integer if self > other."  Whereas a key function is called once for each item and returns the value(s) you want an item sorted on.  See http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/ paying attention specifically to sections titled _Key_Functions_ and _The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter_.  The key parameter was added in Python 2.4.  The cmp parameter was removed in Python 3.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You can pass a function as a key. Doesn't need to be a cmp function.

Comment: @Steve:  Read the exchange.  I'm talking about key functions the whole time.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You are most definitely not talking about key functions the entire time.