# Sort List in Python by two other lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

My question is very similar to these two links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979872/python-how-to-sort-a-complex-list-on-two-different-keys) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-criteria):

I have three different lists.  I want to sort List1 based on List2 (in ascending order).  However, I have repeats in List2.  I then want to sort these repeats by List3 (in descending order).  Confusing enough?

What I have:

```
List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
List2 = [4, 2, 3, 2, 4]
List3 = [0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4]
```

What I want:

```
new_List1 = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'a']
```

'b' comes before 'd' since 0.8 > 0.6.  'e' comes before 'a' since 0.4 > 0.1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this by:

```
paired_sorted = sorted(zip(List2,List3,List1),key = lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]))
l2,l3,l1 = zip(*paired_sorted)
```

In action:

```
>>> List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> List2 = [4, 2, 3, 2, 4]
>>> List3 = [0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4]
>>> paired_sorted = sorted(zip(List2,List3,List1),key = lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]))
>>> l2,l3,l1 = zip(*paired_sorted)
>>> print l1
('b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'a')
```

Here's how it works.  First we match corresponding elements from your lists using `zip`.  We then sort those elements based on the items from List2 first and (negated) List3 second.  Then we just need to pull off the List1 elements again using `zip` and argument unpacking -- Although you could do it easily with a list-comprehension if you wanted to make sure you had a list at the end of the day instead of a tuple.

This gets a little tougher if you can't easily negate the values in List3 -- e.g. if they're strings.  You need to do the sorting in 2 passes:

```
paired = zip(List2,List3,List1)
rev_sorted = sorted(paired,reverse=True,key=lambda x: x[1])  #"minor" sort first
paired_sorted = sorted(rev_sorted,key=lambda x:x[0])         #"major" sort last
l2,l3,l1 = zip(*paired_sorted)
```

(you could use `operator.itemgetter(1)` in place of `lambda x:x[1]` in the above if you prefer).  This works because python sorting is "stable".  It doesn't re-order "equal" elements.

Comment: Not that you need to sort List2 and List3, but nice that your solution does.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yours does too ;-) -- You just don't keep the results.

Answer (score 5):

This requires a decorate-sort-undecorate step:

```
decorated = zip(List1, List2, List3)
decorated.sort(key=lambda v: (v[1], -v[2]))
new_list1 = [v[0] for v in decorated]
```

or, combined into one line:

```
new_list1 = [v[0] for v in sorted(zip(List1, List2, List3), key=lambda v: (v[1], -v[2]))]
```

Output:

```
>>> List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> List2 = [4, 2, 3, 2, 4]
>>> List3 = [0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4]
>>> new_list1 = [v[0] for v in sorted(zip(List1, List2, List3), key=lambda v: (v[1], -v[2]))]
>>> new_list1
['b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'a']
```

Comment: Bonus points if we can figure out how to make this work if negating the elements in List3 wouldn't cause it to be sorted in the opposite order :)  e.g. -- if it contained strings

Comment: @mgilson: I think you could do it in two passes and use `reverse=True`, no?

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah.  I knew that's what it would take, but for some reason I couldn't figure out the logistics until I saw your comment.  I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [v for i, v in sorted(enumerate(List1), key=lambda i_v: (List2[i_v[0]], -List3[i_v[0]]))]
['b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'a']
```

This sorts the index/value pairs by using the indices to get the corresponding values from the other lists to use in the key function used for ordering by `sorted()`, and then extracts just the values using a list comprehension.

Here is a shorter alternative that sorts just the indices and then uses those indices to grab the values from `List1`:

```
>>> [List1[i] for i in sorted(range(len(List1)), key=lambda i: (List2[i], -List3[i]))]
['b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'a']
```